# What does the % symbol do at the end of a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, string

I am working through the Databricks Spark SQL tutorial and found the bit of code below.

I was just wondering what the LIKE command does and what the % at the end of the strings 'murder' and 'homicide' does. I would guess it makes it so that anything can follow those words in the string but I wanted to get confirmation. Thank you!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW HomicidesNewYork AS
    SELECT month(reportDate) AS month, offenseDescription AS offense
    FROM CrimeDataNewYork
    WHERE lower(offenseDescription) LIKE 'murder%' OR lower(offenseDescription) LIKE 'homicide%'
```

Comment: You should read about the LIKE operator: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: The docs on LIKE and % from DataBricks are here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#like

Answer (score 2):

Anything `LIKE 'murder%'` would include:

```
murder
murder downtown
murder is bad mmk
```

The `%` is a wildcard and you use it with LIKE

Answer (score 0):

The '%' is a wildcard used in SQL with the LIKE operator to represent zero, one or more characters.
Consequently, LIKE 'murder%' will match any pattern that starts with the word 'murder'.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE is a check where you want to compare a substring.  The % is the example you have given means anything string that begins with murder.  % is a wildcard in SQL which means it allows for any characters where you place it.

[image: How to use the wildcard:]

Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp for more info on how to use wildcards, table is from here.

Comment: Caution! `like` does care about case. Your table column may permit case insensitive comparisons. MySQL VARCHAR defaults to case-insensitve, Postgres TEXT to case-sensitive (but it adds `ilike` to simplify case-insensitive comparisons.)

Comment: Removed to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thought in this specific example - the lower operator means what the query checks for is always lower case

Answer (score 0):

% is a wildcard character, which is used to substitute any other character(s) in a string.It represents zero, one, or multiple characters.

Wildcard characters are used with the SQL LIKE operator. The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

In your query:

```
WHERE lower(offenseDescription) LIKE 'murder%' OR lower(offenseDescription) LIKE 'homicide%'
```

It will match the following results:

```
murder
murder test
murder123
murderMURDER
homicide
homicide test
homicide123
murderhomicide
```